# Ubuntu 16.04 running too slow even in core i3 PC

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, video, intel, cpu

I have been looking at questions about Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running too slow.
I have concluded that all those asked questions were either having too old PCs or Laptops or Nvidia graphics.

I have a fairly high spec configuration:-
6 GB RAM, Core i3 (2nd gen), SSD 256GB + 1TB HDD

The issue is very serious when I start playing video in chrome of even Firefox for that matter.
There were answers saying tweak with your Chrome settings Andersen  I even did that but the issue persists. Sometimes the system hangs everything and I can see chrome/firefox consuming 100% CPU.
Things used to work really well until 14.04 LTS. I can see a lot of graphics improvement in 16.04 LTS but that has made usage of Laptop quite impossible.

Here are my graphics details in case they can help answering this question.

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:dd000000-dd3fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e000(size=64
```

Comment: having same issue over here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/859290/how-to-troubleshoot-internet-browsing-and-overall-performance-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try out `Compiz Config Settings Manager` and dial back some of the Unity graphic embellishments by enabling `Low Graphics Mode`.

In `terminal`, type:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

In CCSM, go to the `Desktop` section and select `Ubuntu Unity Plugin`. Look at the very bottom and you'll see `Enable Low Graphics Mode`. Check it.

See if that improves the feel a bit.

[image]

Comment: ..continued
But I already tried doing that before posting the question but that did not help .
Not sure what is the is issue that consumes that much of CPU.

Comment: How much swap space do you have set up? What is the `terminal` output of `free -h` after the system has been running for a while?

Comment: The issues is even that is not bottleneck

Comment: Below is output of (free -h)
 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5.7G        2.2G        928M        466M        2.6G        2.8G
Swap:          5.9G          0B        5.9G
and I believe that's quite good.

Comment: Free -h looks fine. Log out of your current login, and log into the Guest account, and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: yes its having the same issue in guest login also.

Comment: sometimes it seems everything has gone to normal and other times its back to the state it was with 100% CPU consumption.

Comment: You could always install `xubuntu-desktop` or `lubuntu-desktop` in the hope that their "lighter" requirements speed things up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even on a power machine, I tend to use low graphic mode. Also turn off setting (in apps) that provide transparent background or alike. It makes a huge difference. I used to use Terminator with a cool looking 10% opacity just to learn that my Cpu was churning away.

Last but not least, and not to start a flame wars, but Unity desktop is not exactly know to be "lightweight". Look to use something like xcfe or even i3wm.